# Create array dynamically inside begin and end

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

How to create an array dynamically inside PostgreSQL?

Consider this e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun( )
RETURNS SETOF void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

i numeric;

BEGIN

 FOR i in 1..10   LOOP
     //I have to create an array as 
     arr1[] ,arr2[] ... based on length
 END LOOP;
END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: so do you want to create array dynamically, loop over array? It's not clear (for me) from your example. You can use `array_append` to add element in array if that's what you need - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Answer (score 9):

There is a special function for this purpose - array_fill:

```
postgres=# select array_fill(0, ARRAY[10]);
      array_fill       
-----------------------
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
(1 row)

postgres=# select array_fill('Hello'::text, ARRAY[10]);
                          array_fill                           
---------------------------------------------------------------
 {Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello}
(1 row)

postgres=# select array_fill(0, ARRAY[3,3]);
        array_fill         
---------------------------
 {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}
(1 row)
```

In PL/pgSQL (but it is significantly slower for large arrays (over 100 items):

```
DO $$
DECLARE
result int[] = '{}';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10
  LOOP
    result := result || 0;
  END LOOP;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', result;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: I dont want to store the values into array. I want to create array as arr1[] ,arr2[], arr3[],arr4[] likewise n number of times.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Why you do it? What do you do?

Comment: using for loop i have to create array. If for loop is executed 4 times then i hav to create 4 arrays as arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4.

Comment: and what you want to do with array later? You have to move or save this data somewhere?

Comment: I have to store values into array and then I have to iterate another for loop based on the values in the array.

Comment: you would to create array of arrays? It is not possible directly in Postgres - it support only multidimensional arrays - you can use a trick with nested type: create type x as (a int[]);  select ARRAY[ROW(ARRAY[10,20]), ROW(ARRAY[10,20,40])]::x[]; But this technique is little bit obscure - and probably using a temporary table is better

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to say which way you should go without knowing your final goal, Pavel Stehule gave you good advice about filling arrays, you can use temporary table to store arrays inside your function.
You can also create a function which returns a set of arrays and then iterate through it, like:

```
create or replace function fun1()
returns setof int[] as
$BODY$
declare
    i int;
begin
    for i in 1..10 loop
        return next array_fill(0, array[i]);
    end loop;
end;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;


create or replace function fun2()
returns setof int as
$BODY$
declare
    a int[];
begin
    for a in select * from fun1() loop
        return next array_length(a, 1);
    end loop;
end;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle frmo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4496b/1)